# Numeric division using BCD format

Tags: c++, numeric

I've two std::deque objects containing (unpacked) BCD numbers. Each byte is one BCD digit. The size is not limited, but there is a MAX_SCALE = 10, so 1 / 3 should result in 0.3333333333. For both objects, the scale and sign is saved:

```
class Numeric
{
   std::deque<uint8_t> m_digits;
   size_t m_scale; // indicates how many digits after "."
   bool sign; // true = positive, false = negative
};
```

Each Numeric object is scaled to 0 before calculation, 10.34 / 2.1 is scaled to 1034 / 210 and the highest scale (2) is recorded for rescale back later.

What is the fastest method to calculate the quotient into a third Numeric object?

I've already implemented addition, substraction und multiplication, but I can't find a good explanation how to implement (fast) divison (with an unlimited number of digits).

Comment: Have you tried standard [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division)?  Is it fast enough?

Comment: It would be a very slow method if the divisor is a really large number.

Comment: not really. It is O(n^2), and IIRC, there is a discussion on how to implement long division in Knuth vol 2. See my answer for another way to implement division if you already have multiplication working.

Comment: also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Newton's method to find 1 / a.

Let  f(x) = 1 / x - a, you want to find f^{-1}(0).

Then

```
x_{n + 1} = x_n - f(x_n) / f'(x_n)
```

converges to f^{-1}(0). This gives us

```
x_{n + 1} = x_n - (1 / x_n - a) / (-1 / x^2)
```

therefore

```
x_{n + 1} = x_n * (2 - a * x_n)
```

converges to 1 / a. You test convergence with the criterion

```
if (|x_{n + 1} - x_n| < tolerance) then stop
```

You roughly need log n multiplications to converge. If multiplications are O(n^2), this is slower than long division for large numbers (O(n^2), vs O(n^2 log n)). Nevertheless, it is quick to implement and not so bad in practice. In fact, some processors use a variant of this scheme to find inverses and perform divisions. Note that if you have a better multiplication algorithm, then Newton's method outperforms long division asymptotically.

As a first guess for x_0, you can set all but the most significant digit to zero, and find its inverse directly.

Example: a = 3425,23. First guess : 1 / a ~ 1 / 3000 ~ 0.0033333333

As an aside, the iteration

```
x_{n + 1} = x_n * (3 - a * x_n^2)
```

will converge to 1 / sqrt(a) (take two leading digits and a small lookup table for the initial guess).

Comment: The Cray-1 supercomputer didn't have a divide instruction; it had an invert instruction which you used with multiply to do a division.

Comment: @Mark: this is the kind of RISC computers which are likely to perform inversion à la Newton. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Is Newton's method only for solving 1 / x?

Comment: @cytrinox: you can solve a lot of things with Newton's method. Look at the Wikipedia article for the general theory. It can appear surprising that division can be performed with it, but historically it has been, and is used in arbirary precision arithmetic libraries (where multiplication is usually O(n log n))

Comment: ah! solving 1 / x is enough :)
But I don't understand how to determine x_0. Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division mention that x_0 = (48/17)-(32/17)*D, but this becomes not a valid result in my tests. For example, what is x_0 if D = 6? And which value should be choosen for tolerance?

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in integer arithmetic: to calculate `10.34 / 2.1`, you want to calculate `10340000000000 / 2100` and then divide by `10^10`. And to calculate `10340000000000 / 2100`, you only need to purchase Knuth vol 2, as  Alexandre C already mentioned. (This is not something that you will ever regret!) I don't think Newton's method is applicable here, unless your numbers are very large.

Comment: I think the point of the question is precisely how to compute such integer long divisions. I mentioned Newton's method because it is not bad and it is very simple to implement. As you said, there are many details in Knuth, but the next simplest thing (after Newton) is [this method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_division).

Comment: @Alexandre: If you are right, why did the OP mention MAX_SCALE at all? That seemed to me like the first thing to clear up.